# show textbox value on same/different page on pressing TAB key

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I have a textbox and when i will write something on that textbox and if pressed TAB key then an alert will come as "please wait" and then i want to display the entered value in that jsp page or different jsp page, that alert is coming but the entered text box value is not displayed, how can it be done?

//**a.jsp**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var obj;
  var TAB = 9;
  function catchTAB(evt,elem)
  {
   obj = elem;
   var keyCode;
   if ("which" in evt)
    {// NN4 & FF &amp; Opera
     keyCode=evt.which;
   } else if ("keyCode" in evt)
    {// Safari & IE4+
  keyCode=evt.keyCode;
 } else if ("keyCode" in window.event)
 {// IE4+
keyCode=window.event.keyCode;
} else if ("which" in window.event)
{
 keyCode=evt.which;
} else  {    alert("the browser don't support");  }

 if (keyCode == TAB)
 {
 obj.value = obj.value + "\t";
 alert("Please wait");
 setTimeout("obj.focus()",1);// the focus is set back to the text input
}
}
</script>
<body>
 <input type="text" name="textboxname" onkeydown="catchTAB(event,this);"/>// after hitting TAB key i want to see that entered value in a.jsp page, how can i do it?
</body>
```

Any help

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to do? Are you trying to have the text input value show up in the alert message?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are able to catch the Tab event, it is then very easy to get the value from that event and populate it anywhere in that page.

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
 var obj;
  var TAB = 9;
  function catchTAB(evt,elem)
  {
   obj = elem;
   var keyCode;
   if ("which" in evt)
    {// NN4 & FF &amp; Opera
     keyCode=evt.which;
   } else if ("keyCode" in evt)
    {// Safari & IE4+
  keyCode=evt.keyCode;
 } else if ("keyCode" in window.event)
 {// IE4+
keyCode=window.event.keyCode;
} else if ("which" in window.event)
{
 keyCode=evt.which;
} else  {    alert("the browser don't support");  }

 if (keyCode == TAB)
 {
 obj.value = obj.value + "\t";
 alert("Please wait");
alert( obj.value);
document.getElementById('textboxNew').value = obj.value;
 setTimeout("obj.focus()",1);// the focus is set back to the text input
}
}
</script>
<body>
 <input type="text" name="textboxname" onkeydown="catchTAB(event,this);"/>// after hitting TAB key i want to see that entered 

value in a.jsp page, how can i do it?

<input type="text" name="textboxNew" id="textboxNew"/>
</body>
```